# If particular terms of a binomial expansion are given then does it need to be a unique expansion?

Tags: binomial-theorem

We have a binomial expansion $(x+y)^n$ , where $x,y,n$ are all some real numbers and are unknown. (n$\in$ I), (x, y ≠ 0)

And we know the numerical values of $(r-2)$th, (r)th and $(r+2)$th terms of the expansion (suppose them to be A,B,C respectively) (numerical value of r is given) . So, will there be only a unique such expansion (if possible) or can there be two such expansions,i.e., we get two values of n.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion will not be unique.

As an simple counterexample, $(x-y)^n$ will have every other term same as $(x + y)^n$, if $r$ is odd.

Two polynomials are the same if and only if all terms are identical. Three terms will not be enough in general.

Comment: Can there be two expansions with different values of n? I tried to solve and got a quadratic equation in 'n'. So there can be max two values of n. But can both be positive integer values?

Comment: @HalfInfinity I have been looking for non-trivial examples (eg $x, y \neq 0$) but to no avail. I am not an expert in diophantine equations. I can say that the generalized binomial theorem applies for all $n \notin \mathbb{Z}^-$ via the gamma function, so you should clarify the question if you are only solving over positive integer values of $n$